# Why does TexStudio move the focus from the search box of pdf to the editor when I am pressing what I want to search?

Tags: texstudio

TexStudio v2.11.2

The interface of TeXStudio contains two parts. One is the editor and the other is the preview of pdf.

I use the search box of the preview of pdf to look for what I want, e.g. "python". But after I press "py", TeXStudio moves the focus from the search box to the editor. If I have paid no attention to the change of focus and press "thon", "thon" will be added to the code in the editor.

Why does this happen? How to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: It is still occurring in 2.12.6.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in v2.12.0. See also https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1922/